# Shaka player failing tests with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, shaka

I have a component including **shaka player** that I want to test with react test library which is based on jest.

```
      ...
      <ShakaPlayer
        autoPlay
        src="http://xxxx/bbb/default/index.mpd"
      />
      ...
```

When running a test on this component, if I make a simplistic test async like this:

```
  it( 'includes a Init button', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render( <Home/> )
    await waitFor( () =>
      expect( getByText( /Init/i ) ).toBeVisible()
    );
  } )
```

Then shaka player is causing the test to fail:

```
    EmeEncryptionSchemePolyfill: EME not found

      at es (node_modules/shaka-player-react/dist/cjs.js:854:374)

  console.debug
    McEncryptionSchemePolyfill: MediaCapabilities not found

      at ns (node_modules/shaka-player-react/dist/cjs.js:859:230)
...

this.target.addEventListener is not a function
TypeError: this.target.addEventListener is not a function
    at new Qc (/Users/Ludo/dev/xxx/saas/xxx/webapp/node_modules/shaka-player-react/dist/cjs.js:228:473)
```

The blocking point is this exception: `this.target.addEventListener is not a function`

It's because the player is in jest which includes a headless brother. Does someone know how to make shaka player not explode in this test environment?